# Poweredge R210 Blinking Blue Light?

Tags: dell-poweredge

Dell Poweredge R210, blinking blue light on the front and the back, now normally this means someone tapped the i button on the front and put it into ID mode, but i tried tapping that button to get it back to solid blue but it just goes solid blue for a second then back to blinking blue.

I contacted Dell and of course their reply was the server was in ID mode and flashing the blue led so the server could be identified, but thats not the case.

I looked through all the logs, no errors, no problems, rebooted and went into the diagnostics, ran through that, everything is perfectly fine.  So other then an annoying blinking light that keeps me wondering, whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the light itself may be malfunctioning. Because that's the only thing that light is good for is identification, it doesn't signal if something is wrong. What I would do is open the chassis up and manually unplug and plug the button back in and see what happens.

Comment: I shut it down and removed power and unplugged the ribbon cable to the front panel and then reseated that, booted back up and the light was steady blue again. So either removing power for a while or reseating the cable seems to have fixed it! Thanks for the suggestion, figured it was something simple.